# Refresh layout page before exporting every atlas page using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, layouts, atlas

I am trying to develop an automatic layout export using PyQGIS. I have several layers with objects and a separate layer to create an atlas of 4 elements.
[image]

I also prepared a layout in which there is a map and 3 blocks with legends containing different layers.
[image]

Each legend block, with the exception of the upper one, has X and Y redefined using the Expression Editor so that the legend block is located one under the other and "sticks" to the previous one. **This works fine if you manually run the atlas preview and click the refresh page button**. Legend blocks, depending on the number of elements, are located under each other and do not climb on top of each other.
Here is example:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def GetItemX(LayoutName, ItemName, feature, parent):
    layout_name = LayoutName
    item_name = ItemName
    
    manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
    layout = manager.layoutByName(layout_name)
    
    item = layout.itemById(item_name)
    item_position = item.positionWithUnits()
    item_x = item_position.x()
    
    return item_x
```

> (Code for collecting Y and Heght is similar)

I want to automate this process using PyQGIS. I created a script that automatically creates an atlas and prescribed at the time of rendering the same page update using layout.refresh(). However, this does not work and as a result I get files where one legend fits on another, i.e. the page is not refreshed and there is no recalculation of X and Y by Expressions set.

My code below:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('Atlas')
atlas = layout.atlas()

atlas.beginRender()
i = 0
while atlas.next():
    layout.refresh()
    layout.updateBounds()
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    pdfpath = 'mypath' + str(i) + '.pdf'
    exporter.exportToPdf(pdfpath, exporter.PdfExportSettings())
    i+=1
atlas.endRender()
```

That's what I get in the end:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Years ago, I wrote a layout exporter that turns selected layers on/off and prints to pdfs.  To refresh the layout, I ran

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(True)

layout.refresh()

exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
```

The `layout.refresh()` might solve your problems.
I just re-read your code, and you are using the refresh().  But you use it before the QgsLayoutExporter(layout).  Would it help if you move the refresh() to after the QgsLayoutExporter(layout)?

Comment: The OP is already using `layout.refresh()`. So, this doesn't answer the question.